# IOTA Node not reachable

Tags: iota-network, java

I would like to make an app to store messages in the Tangle and retrieve them again.

Do I have to run an Iota node on my PC , or can I connect to a neighbou node to make the app?

with this code I always get the error message that the node is not reachable..

```
// I'm trying to connect to this node "http://api.testnet.shimmer.network:14265/"

 IotaAPI api = new IotaAPI.Builder()
        .protocol("http")
        .host("api.testnet.shimmer.network")
        .port("14265")
        .build();
```

where can I find connection information for existing nodes ?

Comment: Where did you find this API endpoint to use from?

Comment: here https://wiki.iota.org/iotajs/how_tos/simple#example-code

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to run, nor own a Iota node to be able to post new blocks(messages) on the tangle.

> where can I find connection information for existing nodes

This is a good question, there was a time, in some part of the [wiki](https://wiki.iota.org/) where this information existed. Now I can not find it.

You could use the different Iota clients to do it using that [endpoint](https://api.testnet.shimmer.network).

If you use your own client or  do a POST request to that endpoint, your block has to fulfill Proof of work. Because I think node's Pow is disabled on that endpoint.

One could use curl to test that the endpoint is working, like explained [here](https://editor.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iotaledger/tips/main/tips/TIP-0025/core-rest-api.yaml)

Changing http://127.0.0.1 to https://api.testnet.shimmer.network .

To fulfill proof of work, refer to this [tip](https://github.com/iotaledger/tips/blob/main/tips/TIP-0012/tip-0012.md) (I believe these are the last specs on this).